# I am receiving EoF error while running load test suit. Could any one tell me why i am receiving it & how to resolve it

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : end tag name  must match start tag name  from line 36 (position: TEXT seen ..., code=null, name=DEERE]... @36:75)

Comment: Can you write your code.

Comment: Please provide the code so that we can understand it, the command you're using to run the test suite, as well as the complete output you're receiving.

This is useful because without this information people will just be speculating to what the problem may be.